# How can i decode in AngularJS a JWT with a public key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, jwt

I'm building an AngularJS site with authentication based in JWT. When I log successfully into the aplication, the backend returns me a JWT and this is stored in localStorage.

I want to receive the roles of the user in the JWT Claims, but I read the token from localstorage and therefore this can be simply modificated (e.g.: using chrome dev tools) and the malicious user can put fake roles in the JWT.

How i can verify the token in the client side using a public key?. I asume the NodeJS server generate the token using their corresponding private key using jwt-simple

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question of "how to decode in AngularJS" is pretty meaningless. AngularJS is a MVVM framework, and it doesn't care about encryption or validation, or any other data structures. You also fail to mention if this is a JWS or JWE token - the former need only validation; the latter decryption. Ultimately, the validation of the claims is up to your server where the real role-based access control happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and the malicious user can put fake roles in the JWT

Why is that an issue? Malicious user cannot produce a valid token w/o knowing a private key and server will validate the JWT upon the next request anyway.

If you want to verify JWT in order to correctly show, say, GUI, you can use JS library for that, e.g. http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/.

Comment: Ok, let's imagine that your client-side app did get a fake token, trusted it and tried to perform some high-privilege action. An app will send a request to the server with fake token and it will fail. So the only thing "hacker" will achieve is to make app _look_ like it's capable of doing lots of things while in fact it will not.

Comment: Again you're right. In fact, the server don't response because the token isn't valid. I only want to verify the token in the client to avoid the "hacker" reach sensitive areas of the app.

Comment: This is fine, and you can use the library mentioned in the answer, it has simple API and supports many algorithms. Keep in mind however that verification will not stop the rogue user from seeing sensitive UI areas of application (it's only a matter of editing live source code in browser console) - unless you're ready to secure static content with tokens as well - in which case client-side verification does not matter as well.

Comment: With "jsjws" i was enable to verify the signed token in the client side. Thanks mate!

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if you think it's good enough.

Comment: I would do it, but I have a poor reputation because this is my first question here. Sorry mate =(

Comment: :) I'm pretty sure you can, just click the empty checkbox mark right below the up and down arrows to the left of the answer. There shouldn't be any restrictions to that.