# Identifying the user using jwt token authentication

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, jwt, jose4j

I am using jersey rest webservice along with JWT with RSA signature token feature for authentication. I was able to successfully create and send token to the front-end. Now after I have achieved this far I am confused about verifying token and also identifying a user making request for resources.

Few questions here:

1. Do I have to decode the jwt token received on front-end to check the
   claims?
2. How do I identify a user requesting for a resource on backend?

Because on few of the posts on SO some people said its not required to decode the token on front end ([check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834080/how-can-i-decode-in-angularjs-a-jwt-with-a-public-key)) while other examples on other sites shows example of decoding the token on front end such as [this](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs)

Now I am confused how to go further on whether I should actually decode a token on front-end or leave it as is? If so how come other examples show decoding on front-end like [this](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs):

```
angular.module('app')
   .factory('Auth', ['$http', '$localStorage', 'urls', function ($http, $localStorage, urls) {
       function urlBase64Decode(str) {
           var output = str.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
           switch (output.length % 4) {
               case 0:
                   break;
               case 2:
                   output += '==';
                   break;
               case 3:
                   output += '=';
                   break;
               default:
                   throw 'Illegal base64url string!';
           }
           return window.atob(output);
       }

       function getClaimsFromToken() {
           var token = $localStorage.token;
           var user = {};
           if (typeof token !== 'undefined') {
               var encoded = token.split('.')[1];
               user = JSON.parse(urlBase64Decode(encoded));
           }
           return user;
       }
```

Token example I am using here:

```
private void authenticate(String email, String password)
    throws Exception {
try {
    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select USR_PRIMARY_EMAIL, USR_PASSWORD from TBL_USER where USR_PRIMARY_EMAIL=? and USR_PASSWORD=?");
    statement.setString(1, email);
    statement.setString(2, password);
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    if (result.next()) {
        System.out.println("User authenticated successfully");

        KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGenerator.initialize(1024);

        KeyPair kp = keyGenerator.genKeyPair();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();
        JWSSigner signer = new RSASSASigner(privateKey);

        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet();
        claimsSet.setSubject("alice");
        claimsSet.setIssuer("https://c2id.com");
        claimsSet.setExpirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000));

        System.out.println("publicKey is: " + publicKey);
        System.out.println("privateKey is: " + privateKey);
        System.out.println("claimsSet is: " + claimsSet);

        SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.RS256),claimsSet);

        signedJWT.sign(signer);
        token = signedJWT.serialize();
        System.out.println("Token is: " + token);

        signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(token);

        System.out.println("signedJWT is: " + signedJWT);

        JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(publicKey);
        assertTrue(signedJWT.verify(verifier));
        assertEquals("alice", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject());
        assertEquals("https://c2id.com", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer());
        assertTrue(new Date().before(signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime()));
    } else {
        System.out.println("User doesn't exist");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("DB related Error");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Also one more issue is the token generated using nimbus+jose_JWT(RSA signature) I am not able to decode in angular [auth0](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt) library. Is it because I am using public key?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I have to decode the jwt token received on front-end to check the claims?

Yes. The JWT claims set is base64URL-encoded JSON, so you need to decode in order to read it.

---

> How do I identify a user requesting for a resource on backend?

The `sub` claim is optional, but practically every JWT provider will issue all tokens with a subject ID that identifies the requester. From the JWT spec:

> The "sub" (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the
>      subject of the JWT.  The claims in a JWT are normally statements
>      about the subject.  The subject value MUST either be scoped to be
>      locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique.
>      The processing of this claim is generally application specific.  The
>      "sub" value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI
>      value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

---

> Also one more issue is the token generated using nimbus+jose_JWT(RSA signature) I am not able to decode in angular auth0 library. Is it because I am using public key?

No. All JWT claim sets are base64URL-encoded JSON independently of signature method, so you should be able to decode it.

Comment: HI Rodrigo. Thank you so much for your answer. I am able to properly decode the token now but the thing is its only returning the payload info such as `sub`,`iss` and `exp` but no header and signature? Do I need those values as well to identify the user? and also to insert authorization information into header? or only just payload info is enough?

Comment: When calling an API that accepts JWT, you just pass the whole JWT in the `Authorization` header (e.g. `Authorization: Bearer eyJ...`). JWT libraries will let you access the claims set when decoding a token. Accessing the header is usually unnecessary because you should know a priori which signing algorithm you expect (see https://auth0.com/blog/2015/03/31/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/). It's also unnecessary to access the signature manually, since you should use the library's verification methods directly.